# Finite sum of products of binomial coefficients and quadratic polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

How can I calculate the value of such a sum?

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (2k^2-3k+1){n\choose k}$

Should I split it into three sums? But then I don't know what to do with $k^2{n\choose k}$. I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k} = 2^n$. But that isn't much help, is it? Or maybe I should use generating function? Then $\sum_{k\ge0} {n\choose k} x^k = (1+x)^n$

Please, help.

Thank you.

Comment: consider $\sum x^k \left({n \atop k}\right)$ and differentiate.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see it that clearly: differentiating wrt $\,x\,$ gives $\,\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\,$....How does this help with $\,2\sum_{k=0}^nk^2\binom{n}{k}\,$ , for example?

Comment: I think you need to differentiate it and then multiply by x, then differentiate it again and again multiply by x.

Comment: just for you to check answer it should be $2^{n-1}(n^2-2n+2)$

Comment: I think I'm lost. $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (2k^2-3k+1){n\choose k} x^n = 2 \sum_{k \ge 0} k^2{n\choose k}x^n -3 \sum_{k \ge 0} k{n\choose k}x^n + \sum_{k \ge 0}{n\choose k}x^n$ Then after differentiation I change it into closed forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following facts may be helpful:

(a) $\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n}{k}$;

(b) $k\dbinom{n}{k}=n\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$;

(c) $k(k-1)\dbinom{n}{k}=n(n-1)\dbinom{n-2}{k-2}$.

Now express $2k^2-k+1$ as a linear combination of $1$, $k$, and $k(k-1)$.

Comment: So the solution is $2n(n-1) \cdot 2^{n-2} -n \cdot 2^{n-1} + 2^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get. Simple, eh? Linear algebra can be useful!

Comment: Yes, very useful, indeed. Thanks a lot. I was planning to use generating functions, but what you came up with is a lot simpler and quicker :)

Comment: Generating functions give a very nice approach. But variety is a good thing.